# Get the component resolved in page using core service api or tom.net api

Tags: 2011, 2013, core-service, tom.net

I am looking to get the  component resolved in page using core service..

We can find item used in how many places by this

```
UsedItemsFilterData usedItemsFilterData = new UsedItemsFilterData();
return client.GetListXml(tcmID, usedItemsFilterData)
```

i need solution for `itemType` component in which pages it got used and ,does any one having some link or post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all component(linked Component) linked to pages

```
            UsedItemsFilterData filter = new UsedItemsFilterData();
            filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component };
            XElement xmllist= client.GetListXml("tcm:aaa-bbbb-64", filter);
            //to get list of all component for pages(Level1)
            list = (xBundles.DescendantNodes()).ToList<XNode>();
            foreach (XElement foo in list)
            {
                if (foo.HasAttributes == true)
                    {
                        XElement xmllist2= client.GetListXml(foo.FirstAttribute.Value,filter);//get all component from component(level 2)
                        List<XNode> List2 = new List<XNode>();
                        List2 = (xmllist2.DescendantNodes()).ToList<XNode>();
                        foreach(XElement foo1 in List2)
                            {
//repeat same loop structure to get next level
                            if (foo1.HasAttributes == true)
                                     {
                             //for level 2
                                     }     
                             }

              }  
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there.

To determine all pages that use a given component, I would use the following code:

```
UsingItemsFilterData pagesFilter = new UsingItemsFilterData();
pagesFilter.ItemTypes = new [] {ItemType.Page};
return client.GetListXml(componentId, pagesFilter);
```